# Rail Object Relationships & JSON Rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, activerecord

I already know how to include the relationships of has_many & has_one relationships into my JSON rendering.  I even know how to exclude certain attributes when doing so.  For those that don't know here's a good post:

[Rails Object Relationships and JSON Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462754/rails-object-relationships-and-json-rendering)

However, what I don't know how to do is have it use the as_json on the child object so I don't have to redeclare it on every parent relationship.

So if I have something like this...

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

  def as_json(options={ })
    super({ :except => :Password, :include => [:orders] }.merge(options))
  end
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :customer

  def as_json(options={ })
    super({ :include => [:customer] }.merge(options))
  end
end
```

It ends up sending back the Customer password when you view it from the Order perspective.

Ideally I'd want it to follow the rules of the as_json defined in the model so I don't have to put in exceptions for the inclusion of :customer on every child object.

P.S. - This is just an example not a real world scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would encourage you to use the RABL gem versus overriding `as_json` for all of your models.  It's much easier to define your JSON responses using only the parameters / relationships you want.  You can also easily create parent/children nesting.

https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

Comment: How do you dynamically change the output using rabl?  Sometimes I want to change what is returned in the json based on whom is requesting the data.

Comment: You use the same Ruby syntax as you normally would (i.e. `if` and `unless` statements among other things).