# Rails, how to convert data with association, that has association, to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Is it possible to convert data with association, that has association, to json?

Let's assume we have these models and associations:

```
    class Country < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :citizens
    end

    class Citizen < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :habits
     belongs_to :country
    end

    class Habit < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :citizen
    end
```

A controller may look like this:

```
country = Country.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: country }
end
```

[As already answered in another stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819551/retrieve-associations-in-angularjs-rails-using-ngresource), one can include associations with this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: country.as_json(include: :citizens) }
end
```

Is there a way, to include habits as well? Is it possible to have a json with the country, its citizens and the habits of the citizens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, its definitely possible. Try this code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: country.as_json(include: { citizens: { include: :habits }}) }
end
```

You can refer to the documentation for more details. [Go here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html)